# C# count consecutive duplicates in List<string>

Tags: c#, performance, list, duplicates

I have a List of strings and want to count the duplicates in it, to work with this information later. To simply count the duplicates would be very easy, but unfortunately I just want to count the consecutive duplicates.

Let us say we have a list with this string items in it:

> "1A","3B","5X","7Q","2W","2G","2J","1A","2A"

Now I want to count the duplicates in this list. **I just will look at the first char of each string, the other characters in the string can be ignored!**
What we get is *2x "1%*" and *3x "2%"*, what i actually want to get is consecutive duplicates, so my result should look like *3x "2%"*. The *2x "1A"* has to be ignored, they are not in a row.
(% = place holder)

I wrote a code that loops through the list and compares one string with the next one

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    char first = list[i][0];

    if ((i + 1) == list.Count) break;
    char second = list[(i + 1)][0];

    if (first == second)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I guess you can imagine that this code is a very ugly way to do this especially if you want to work with the output. Also my code can´t handle the features I need.

The code I am looking for, must be able to deal with two feature I want to implement. First, a row of duplicates does not end if the last element of my list is equal to the first element of the list.

For example:

> "1A","1B","5X","7Q","2J","1I"

The "1%" has to be detected as duplicate, because of the "1I" and "1A" which are "in a row". If you would loop through the list you just break up at the end of the list if the first and last element are not equal.

pseudo code:

```
if(list.First()[0] != list.Last()[0])
```

The second feature I want to implement is, that the items in the list that are not duplicates, with a "duplicate count" over 4 will be deleted. If there is not a single duplicate row with a "duplicate count" or length over 4 I want to return.

For example:

> "1A","1B","5X","3Q","1J","1I"

duplicate count == 4 so return

> "1A","1B","1X","3Q","1J","1I"

duplicate `count == 5`, save this five items, delete any other item in the list.

> "1A","1B","1X","3Q","1I","1Z","1Z"

duplicate count == 6, save this six items, delete any other item in the list.

**Notice:
Just the first char of each string matters. The input list will have 7 items, not a single item more or less. There is no result list, the old one has to be updated. If the duplicate count is under or equal to 4, then there is no work to do, simply return.
There will not be more than 5 duplicates in a row. I have to check billion of list, so performance is really important**

As they don´t teach any better English in German schools, I hope anyone understand what my problem is and is willing to help me out.

This is not part of any homework.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: With "in a row" you actually mean consecutive duplicates?

Comment: What is the best way to change my code or give any input how you would work with the problem ;) With "in a row" i mean consecutive, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to group items beginning with the same char in lists. The result of this grouping will be a `List<List<string>>`. This makes it easier to work with groups.

```
var list = new List<string> {
    "1A", "3B", "5X", "7Q", "2W", "2G", "2J", "1B", "1C", "1D", "1E"
};
var groups = new List<List<string>>();

char lastChar = (char)0; // We assume that NUL will never be used as first char.
List<string> group = null;
foreach (string s in list) {
    if (s[0] != lastChar) {
        group = new List<string>();
        groups.Add(group);
        lastChar = s[0];
    }
    group.Add(s);
}

// Join the first and the last group if their first char is equal
int lastIndex = groups.Count - 1;
if (groups.Count > 2 && groups[0][0][0] == groups[lastIndex][0][0]) {
    // Insert the elements of the last group to the first group
    groups[0].InsertRange(0, groups[lastIndex]);
    // and delete the last group
    groups.RemoveAt(lastIndex);
}

//TODO: Remove test
foreach (List<string> g in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine(g[0][0]);
    foreach (string s in g) {
        Console.WriteLine("   " + s);
    }
}

// Now create a list with items of groups having more than 4 duplicates 
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (List<string> g in groups) {
    if (g.Count > 4) {
        result.AddRange(g);
    }
}

//TODO: Remove test
Console.WriteLine("--------");
foreach (string s in result) {
    Console.Write(s);
    Console.Write("  ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Little changes and it worked for me, thank you! A single run needs about 0.00003 - 0.00004 seconds, fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

What you can use here is a method that is capable of grouping consecutive items while a condition is met:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Once we have this helper method we can write your query in a reasonably straightforward manor:

```
var query = data.GroupWhile((prev, current) => prev[0] == current[0])
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Character = group.First()[0],
        Count = group.Count(),
    });
```

Comment: I cant simply use it like var query = list.GroupWhile((prev, current) => prev[0] == current[0])
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Character = group.First()[0],
        Count = group.Count(),
    }); I guess I overlook the obvious

Comment: @user3868224 And why can't you?